# Can't see HTTP/S traffic from an android app using Fiddler

Tags: android, https, fiddler

I am trying to catch all the traffic that my android app is generating so I installed Fiddler on my desktop and set it up to catch android traffic. I can capture all the traffic from a browser or an app except from my own app. (I am talking about android app and android browser)

This are the steps I followed to catch the traffic: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid.

My App is sending some data to a service. I checked the service and the data was received so there was no problem in sending the data. 

Has any of you encountered this before?

Comment: This suggests that your Android application isn't properly adopting the device's default proxy settings. What HTTP/HTTPS stack are you using?

Comment: I am using a custom one and it's not made my me. I think that might be the problem.